# List<Serializable> to string

Tags: java

My class looks like:

The follwong code comes under MethodCall class:

```
public static class InnerValue {
  @XmlElementRef(name = "string", type = JAXBElement.class)
  @XmlMixed
  protected List<Serializable> content;

  public List<Serializable> getContent() {
    if (content == null) {
      content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
    }
    return this.content;
  }
}
```

When i try to call the Innervalue's `getContent` method it returns object, when i try to convert the Object to String i am failing.

I used the following code to convert it from Object to String, but still it is displaying Object.

```
System.out.println(MethodCall.getContent.toSting())
```

Comment: is this a copy typo? `.getContent.toSting())`

Comment: What exact result do you expect?

Comment: You have to make sure all the objects in the list have sensible `toString` methods. Otherwise you will see the default `MyClass@def0912` style output.

Comment: getContent return type List<Serializable> so it will return object

Comment: How can i get the value of content as string.

Answer (score 2):

The call `System.out.println(MethodCall.getContent().toSting());` will not even compile. If that compiles, then you have a static `getContent()` method in your MethodCall class, and that is the method that gets called.

The method `getContent()` method in your question is not static, so you will need an instance of its class to call it, like this:

```
InnerValue innerValue = new InnerValue();
System.out.println(innerValue.getContent());
```

When you do this, do not forget the import:

```
import <yourpackagename>.MethodCall.InnerValue;
```

Creating an `InnerValue` instance like this does not make much sense, however, since the content list is inevitably going to be empty...

---

---

**As for how to print the contents of a list**, consider this example:

```
    class SerializableImpl implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    };

    List<Serializable> list = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
    list.add(new SerializableImpl());

    System.out.println(list);
```

Using this code, I will get the output:

```
[test.MyTestClass$1SerializableImpl@1befab0]
```

This is expected, because the ArrayList implementation calls `toString()` on each of the entries in the list. But since we did not define a `toString()` for the class `SerializableImpl`, the default `toString()` method in the `Object` class gets called. How do we fix this? Consider this alternative of the code above:

```
    class SerializableInteger implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int value;

        public SerializableInteger(int value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return "value = " + value;
        }
    };

    List<Serializable> list = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
    list.add(new SerializableInteger(42));

    System.out.println(list);
```

What happens now? Well... Since we defined a `toString()` method for the `SerializableInteger` class, that method will be called, and we will receive the output:

```
[value = 42]
```

---

**So, in summary:** When you call `toString()` on a `List`, the `toString()` methods of the entries in the list will be called. So if you want readable output, make sure that all objects that you add to your list have `toString()` methods defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
System.out.println(MethodCall.getContent()+"");
```

Comment: I am sure its working, im also sure the voting will be -30 :D